# Texturing imported mesh

Tags: blender, godot

I am importing a card mesh (beveled plane with some thickness) from blender into Godot. I want to apply two different textures on the front and back face of the mesh inside Godot. All the rest of the faces need not have any material / texture (maybe just a spatial material with albedo).
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Godot does not have tooling for dividing surfaces. Thus, do it in blender. You want to give different material in blender to the parts that must have different materials in Godot.

It is possible to generate and to modify models in Godot using scripts. So doing this entirely in Godot is possible. However, it is much easier to do the required work in Blender.

Godot will only understand the simplest Blender materials. But, you can always modify or replace the materials on Godot. The point is to have materials assigned in Blender, even if they aren't correct.

---

**Blender**

*Now, I'm not a blender expert, so I could be getting things wrong here.*

You want to select the mesh, go to the materials panel (it has a ball icon and you find it on the bottom right).

You should see a list of material slots on the top of the panel. You can add a material slots with the "+" button on the right of the list (the "-" button is to remove them). To assign faces to a material slot, go to edit mode, select the faces, then select the material slot and click "assign".

You can also select a material for your material slot. Below the list of material slots there is a button with that ball icon… It allows you to pick an existing material to add it to the mesh. You don't have any select, on the right of the ball button you get a button to create a new material. Otherwise you get a box that allows to rename the material, and you also get options to duplicate the material, and to delete it.

---

Thus, make material slots for the faces you want to able to change their material in Godot. And then export the model.

I recommend to use gltf format, which is the best supported in Godot (although other format can also work).

Godot will extract material resources on the same folder. Thus, if you have multiple models on the same folder, and Godot extract material resources for all of them in that same folder… Which could lead to materials of one model overwriting the materials of another model. Sometimes you do actually want to consolidate materials like. Thus, take extra care when naming the materials. *And if you are bringing models from third party, consider putting them on folders on their own to avoid problems.* You can always re-asign materials in Godot after the fact.

---

**Godot**

In Godot you can:

- Make an scene and add the model to it. This is composition. You can overwrite the properties of the model in Godot (You can enable editable children to access them). It poses no problem with replacing the model, or if you update it. *I recommend starting with this option.*
- Open the model, and choose to create an inherited scene. This is extension. It will pose no problem if you update the model. But it won't let you replace the model with a different one, and it limits the modification you can do, making this one the most strict option. *I don't recommend this option.*
- Open the model and save it as a new scene. Your new scene will be mostly disconnected form the file. Which also means that if you update it, you will not see it reflected on the scene. *It might be better for the exported game, so perhaps this is something to try when release approaches. Your new scene can replace the model where you were using it. And then you can remove the model (or exclude it from the export).*

Either way, you want to find the materials you want to replace.

You will find three places you can set a material:

- Materials on the `Mesh`. These materials apply to every place where the same `Mesh` is used. *These are the ones you probably want to set.*
- Materials on the `MeshInstance`. These material apply only to the present `MeshInstance`, and take priority over the `Mesh` materials. *If you need to change the materials of a single instance without affecting the other, use these.*
- Material override on the `MeshInstance`. This takes priority over the other materials, and applies to the whole mesh. *Usually you would use this form code for effects.*

In Godot you can create Spatial Materials or Shader Materials. And the Shader Materials will have either a Shader (written in Godot Shader Language) or a VisualShader (done graphically connecting nodes in a graph editor).

I would encourage to reuse Shaders/VisualShaders whenever possible. You can export uniforms form them and have them configured differently for different materials. This is because compiling shaders is slow, so the more you reuse them the less impact shader compilation will have in performance.

By the way, you can use the Orphan Resource Explorer tool to find if there are materials or shaders you are not using, and consider removing them.